# javascript/php back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
            if (file_exists($filedir)) {
            ?>
                <script>alert('File "<?php echo "$filename"; ?>" already exists.');</script>
            <?php
            echo <<<HERE
            <input action="action" type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
HERE;
```

So, how can i embed heredoc part of script into javascript alert box, in order to have alert message and back button in the same alert box ? I've tried to add:

```
header("Location:    ");
```

after the alert box, but that sends me back one page without the javascript alert message.

Thx for the help

Comment: You perhaps should create a modal dialog box instead of an alert box. There are multiple ways of doing this simply, such as using JQuery UI dialog boxes or Bootstrap. Also I would suggest you avoid reinventing the wheel. There are a number of file upload scripts available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe javascript confirm() is what you want?

[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp](http://W3Schools%20Confirm)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
echo <<<HERE
<script>alert('File "$filename" already exists.<input action="action" type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" />')</script>
HERE;
```

but that wont show button, for that you have to use confirm or prompt javascript methods

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
alert('Go back'); window.location.href = "home.php";
```